# Google Translate inserting extra spaces in original formulas

Tags: google-translate

This behavior is old, but to this day it still happens.

If I insert any formula to be translated, https://translate.google.com inserts extra spaces (in my example, from Portuguese to English).

Example. The original `1+1; 2-2; 3*3; 4/4` in translated to `1 + 1; 2-2; 3 * 3; 4/4`.

In this case, you can see extra spaces between `+` and `*`.

How to avoid this?

Comment: It does the same thing periodically with foreign language translation, often after a ":", but sometimes intermittently throughout a document. This causes words to be split, apparently prior to translation as the word split up is not translated properly. Wish I knew the answer to this. Maybe some Word document setting?